# type hinting the __call__() magic method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I use a simple, yet powerful class that acts like a database table, complete with a built-in filter method. Here is a small subset of it.

PyCharm does not show a type hint for #3.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Record:
    ID: int


class Table(list):
    """Like a database table.

    Usage:
    table = Table([Record(123), ...])
    >> table.filter(123)
    Record(123)
    """
    def __call__(self, ID) -> Record:
        return self.filter(ID)

    def filter(self, ID) -> Record:
        return Table(x for x in self if x.ID == ID)[0]


table = Table([Record(123)])

table[0].               # 1. This works. ".ID" Pops up after typing the period.
table.filter(123).      # 2. This works too.
table(123).             # 3. Crickets :-(. Nothing pops up after typing the period.
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that `Table` subclasses `list`. If we implement the required container methods on `Table` instead of subclassing `list` then the autocomplete works as expected, for example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Record:
    ID: int


class Table:
    def __init__(self, items):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, ID) -> Record:
        ...

    def __call__(self, ID) -> Record:
        return self.filter(ID)

    def filter(self, ID) -> Record:
        return Table(x for x in self if x.ID == ID)[0]


table = Table([Record(123)])
table[0].          # works
table.filter(123). # works
table(123).        # works
```

I tested on PyCharm Professional 2018.3.2.

You may see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for additional info on emulating container types.

Comment: Interesting. Is this on purpose, or is it a type hinting bug?

Comment: looks like a bug in pycharm to me, I'm actually surprised `1.` tab completes given `Table` extends `list` and not `List[Record]`

Comment: @ChaimG I agree with @AnthonySottile - it looks like a PyCharm bug. That said I think this is kind of an edge case given it is more typical to implement the container methods yourself vs deriving from `list` directly.

Comment: @AnthonySottile when initializing the Table with `table = Table([Record(123)])` #1 does not autocomplete.

Comment: @ChrisHunt: How would I type hint custom container methods?